# User Control does not show buttons after they have been replaced

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a usercontrol that shows buttons loaded from XML.
It is an overload of the Button, but only to enable extra data on the button

When the program first loads the buttons is shown OK, but if i change the XML and do the entire build and add process again on the control, the buttons is not shown.

I think it might be be releated to the paint process, because if i have a breakpoint in the drawing function it also do not show the buttons

Here are the function that adds the buttons:

_mButtonList is populated in the XML load function

I hope anybody can help :-)

```
    List<posButton> _buttons = new List<posButton>();

    private void generate_Buttons()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Generate buttons");
        try
        {
            SuspendLayout();

            Controls.Clear();

            foreach (posButton b in _buttons)
                b.Dispose();

            _buttons.Clear();

            foreach (posButton pb in _mButtonList)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("  ---  " + pb.Name + " - " + pb.Text + " - Location: " + pb.Location.X + "," + pb.Location.Y + " - Size: " + pb.Size.Width + "," + pb.Size.Height);
                _buttons.Add(pb.Get_Button(Size, _oneUnitWidth));

                _buttons[_buttons.Count - 1].BringToFront();
                _buttons[_buttons.Count - 1].Click += e_uc_ButtonBox_Click;
                Controls.Add(_buttons[_buttons.Count - 1]);
                _buttons[_buttons.Count - 1].Invalidate();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Invalidate();
            ResumeLayout(true);
            Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a very specific question related to your business code and we don't have all the code to try help you. A quick look at your code, seems ok but can't do more than that without more info. Did you breakpoint at pb.Get_Button(Size, _oneUnitWidth) it returns buttons?

Comment: by the way, the code looks messy, just declare a variable of button and use it instead of accessing the list, like: var btn = pb.Get_Button(Size, _oneUnitWidth);

Comment: Hi and thanks.Your proposal to change from list to variable solved the problem. The reason for using the list was to be able to dispose the buttons on refresh